# Linking Geoportal Map Preview to a Geoserver service?

Tags: geoserver, geoportal

I am very new to Geoportal and Geoserver

I have an installation of Geoportal. In the metadata of a resource I can indicate a URL link. I have seen that depending of the linked data the "Preview link" is shown. I also have a Geoserver serving WCS,WMS and WFS services.

What do I need to put in the link URL of a Geoportal resource so when I click preview the request is sent to Geoserver and a shape or grid is rendered in the preview Window? Or if it has to be WMS which image is supported by the preview window?

Please let me know if I am totally confused about linking Geoportal and Geoserver.

Many thanks,
Carlos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your geoportal:

- login as administrator
- open the Administration tab
- Select the link 'Add' at the top
- Click 'Proceed' (your page should have selected the option 'Register resource on the network' by default)
- In the box 'Host URL', enter the getcapabilities URL to the WCS, WFS, or WMS service endpoint from your Geoserver. Typically this will be something like:

  http://services.ogc.noaa.gov/geoserver/geoss_water_sba/wms?request=getcapabilities
- Scroll to the bottom of the screen and click 'Create and Close'
- In the administration page, select the new item (should be at the top of the list) and 'for the selected records' choose 'Set as Approved' and click 'Execute Action'
- open the Search tab
- click 'Search'
- click the title of the top result (this is the one you registered)
- click 'Preview'
- enjoy!

I registered the above Geoserver WMS in our sandbox Geoportal where it can be [previewed](http://gptogc.esri.com/geoportal/catalog/search/resource/livedata-preview.page?uuid=%7BBDFE0214-98BE-4432-AC4A-5153756DE8CD%7D&url=http%3A%2F%2Fservices.ogc.noaa.gov%2Fgeoserver%2Fgeoss_water_sba%2Fwms%3Frequest%3DGetCapabilities%26service%3DWMS%26version%3D1.3.0&resourceType=wms&info=%2Fgeoportal%2Frest%2Fdocument%3Ff%3Dhtml%26showRelativeUrl%3Dtrue%26id%3D%257BBDFE0214-98BE-4432-AC4A-5153756DE8CD%257D) (turn off the basemap if you have a hard time seeing the service).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. However If I declare it as a service the metadata that I get is from the service. But if I already have an entry in GeoPortal with completed FGDC metadata and the layer is in GeoServer how can I use the Map preview?

Comment: I though that maybe by configuring "resourceLinkBuilder.preview.filter" to not include services would help but <parameter key="resourceLinkBuilder.preview.filter" value=""/> does not allow preview of resource URL :-(

Comment: My resource url is for example:  http://data.ilri.org:8080/geoserver/nurc/Arc_Sample/wms?request=getcapabilities